# C# Route filters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I was wondering if there is anyway to add a filter before routes in Visual C# MVC.

I have a `Portal` Area where I want to check if the User is logged in yes/no.

So people can access `Portal/Login` but if they try to access `Portal/Orders` or any unauthorized content I want to be able to redirect them back to `Portal/Login`.

I've worked with PHP Frameworks and I'm new to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Typically you apply the `[Authorize]` attribute to the controller and then the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute to the login/register method. Refer [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx) for explanation.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for the link! However I got a LoginController and RegisterController. I smell this is bad practice, how is this solved in ASP?

Comment: Typically you just have `AccountController` which includes methods such as `Login()`, `Register()`, `ChangePassword()` etc. If you create a new project in VS with forms authentication, this will all be created for you so you can look at how it all works.

Comment: But I got a Portal Area so it's a bit different. If I use my HomeController with a Login() action it wont work because then on `Portal/Login` its looking for a LoginController..

Answer (score 0):

`[Authorze]` is the correct direction for this but I would write a custom authorize attribute to handle the redirect(s) breaking you away from the `Account` controller that's built in. I love that MVC/.NET is so flexible like this :)

You could have something along the lines of:

```
public class MyCustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/controller_name/view_name");
        }
    }


    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
       if (httpContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");

        if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

        if (httpContext.User.IsInRole("MyPreferredRole"))
            return true;

        return false;
    }

}
```

Then, in your controllers you can use `[MyCustomAuthorize]` instead of `[Authorize]`. The `AuthorizeCore` method of this can be customised as per your requirements. Mine is just an example. For example, you could pass in some relevant params to a constructor for the `MyCustomAuthorize` class and validate those in `AuthorizeCore`.

Answer (score 0):

For Non-Core WebAPI you would inherit your custom Authorization attribute from System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute and override OnAuthorization.

```
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
.
.
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    { ... }
}
```

If the result of code in OnAuthorization is the request should be rejected, set the actionContext.Response.

```
actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

Not setting the Response will result in allowing the request to continue through to the route.